# Difficulty plotting 3D functions in my pyside/sympy/matplotlin function plotter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy, pyside

I'm currently developing a function plotter GUI application using PySide6. The application allows users to enter a mathematical function as a string, which is then parsed and plotted. While the application works fine for 2D functions, I'm encountering difficulties when plotting 3D functions.

In my implementation, I use SymPy to parse the function string and generate the data points for plotting. The issue arises when I try to reshape the data into the appropriate shape for the plot_surface function in Matplotlib.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```
import re

import numpy as np
import sympy
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class FunctionProcessor():
...
    def parse_3d_function(self):
        self.function_string = self.function_string.replace("^", "**")
        x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
        function = sympy.sympify(self.function_string)

        x_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
        y_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)

        x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid(x_data, y_data)
        z_data = np.array([function.subs({x: xi, y: yi}) for xi, yi in zip(x_data, y_data)])

        return x_data, y_data, z_data
```

```
import numpy as np
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QLabel,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSlider, QCheckBox
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from numpy import meshgrid

from backend.function_processor import FunctionProcessor
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
class Plotter(QMainWindow):
...
    def plot_3d(self):
        self.function_processor = FunctionProcessor(self,
                                                    self.function_3d_input.text(),
                                                    self.xmin_input.text(),
                                                    self.xmax_input.text())
        self.function_processor.validate_3d_function()
        x_data, y_data, z_data = self.function_processor.parse_3d_function()
        x_data, y_data = meshgrid(x_data, y_data)
        self.figure.clear()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        self.ax.plot_surface(x_data, y_data, z_data)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

the error i get
`ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.`

i tried to search the docs, found that sympy has plot3d function but i need the figure embdeed in the GUI not in a separite window

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Why are there 2 `meshgrid` in your code?

`parse_3d_function` returns 3 arrays, including `x_data` and `y_data`, which are obtained inside this function by

```py
        x_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
        y_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)

        x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid(x_data, y_data)
```

And then what you do with it, inside `plot_3d` is

```py
        x_data, y_data, z_data = self.function_processor.parse_3d_function()
        x_data, y_data = meshgrid(x_data, y_data)
```

So, `x_data, y_data` are a meshgrid of a meshgrid?

That means something, sure, but probably not what you want

### 2. No zip here

No `zip` if you want to compute `z` for all possible combinatins of `x` and `y`!

```py
z_data = np.array([function.subs({x: xi, y: yi}) for xi, yi in zip(x_data, y_data)])
```

Is probably not doing what you expect neither. `xi` and `yi` here are "lines" of x and y values.
If that "function.subs" thing is vectorized, then, no problem. It can work on a whole line of x and y, and compute a line of result.
But if that is so, then, why not just call `function.subs({x:x_data, y:y_data})`. If it is vectorized, then it should work too.

If the function is not vectorized, on the other hand, that is if `x` and `y` are supposed to be just scalar, then `zip` wont descend 2 steps. It won't do a 2 nested loop iteration of both grid in parallel.

You need to do that by yourself. For example (still using your "pure python compound list" style. But the best way should be to rely on vectorization. We don't know what your `function.sub` is, but if it comes from sympify, it is probably not.

So

```py
z_data = np.array([[function.subs({x:x, y:y}) for x in x_data] for y in y_data])
```

With `x_data` and `y_data` being 1d-arrays (so no meshgrid prior to that)

### 3. No meshgrid : broadcasting

And, btw, if the were vectorized, then it another example of unnecessary usage of `meshgrid`. Broadcasting would have been sufficient.

```py
x_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
y_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
z_data = fn(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None])
# ...
ax.plot_surface(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None], z_data)
```

All that `meshgrid` does here is waste good memory. Plus, there might be some optimization inside `function.subs` coming from the fact that `x` and `y` are 2 essentially 1d-arrays, not 2d. For example, if you are computing `x²+y²`, then `x_data[None,:]**2+y_data[:,None]**2` is 2N `**2` operations (N for x, N for y), then N² additions. While `x,y=np.meshgrid(x_data,y_data); x**2+y**2` are 2N² `**2` operations (N² for x, N² for y) and N² additions. Not counting the cost of `meshgrid` itself.

So, no meshgrid when broadcasting is enough.

Here, you haven't any vectorized function. But as you've seen (section 2 of this answer), the way to compute the grid of `z` does not use `meshgrid` neither

```py
x_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
y_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
z_data = np.array([[function.subs({x:x, y:y}) for x in x_data] for y in y_data])
# ...
ax.plot_surface(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None], z_data)
```

### 4. Vectorization of `function.subs

You could, somehow vectorize this function, so that it behaves more like a classical numpy function

```py
fn=np.vectorized(lambda xi,yi:function.subs({x:xi,y:yi}))
x_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
y_data = np.linspace(self.x_range[0], self.x_range[1], 101)
z_data = fn(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None])
ax.plot_surface(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None], z_data)
```

It doesn't provide meaningful acceleration. Is is not truly vectorized (`function.subs` is still called 101² times). But it has the advantage to put you back in a quite classical situation: I have vectors of x and y, and I want to compute z for all possible x and y, from a numpy operation. And that is classicaly done by

```py
ax.plot_surface(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None], numpyOp(x_data[None,:], y_data[:,None]))
```

Which is what I did, once I vectorized your function.

(Well, in reality, if I trust what I see often here, it is "classically"
done with

```py
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x_data,y_data)
ax.plot_surface(xx,yy,numpyOp(xx,yy))
```

But, as I said, that is a mistake. Like 95% of usage of `meshgrid` you see, it is a waste of memory and computation time that could be better done by broadcasting)